# Spatchcocked turkey cooking time

Tags: turkey

How long should I plan on cooking a 16 pound spatchcocked turkey?  What temperature would be best to cook a 16 pound spatchcocked turkey?

Answer (score 2):

Kenji at [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/11/how-to-spatchcock-cook-turkey-thanksgiving-fast-easy-way-spatchcocked.html) recommends 450F for 80 minutes for a 12-14 pound bird "until an instant read thermometer inserted into the deepest part of the breast registers 150°F, and the thighs register at least 165°F". I would expect a 16 pound bird to take about 20 minutes longer (just by figuring a simple ratio).

Serious Eats goes deeply into turkey spatchcocking, so I recommend taking the time to read the articles.

His video [here](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/11/video-how-to-spatchcock-turkey-thanksgiving.html) is great.

Comment: It's hard to go wrong following the advice at Serious Eats. Great answer Jolenealaska!

Tip: Time is just a reference - the temperature of the meat is what tells you it's done. Good luck!

(I had the ?pleasure? of helping joint 20 turkey's last Sunday - Cooked the limbs on the flattop until crispy then into the oven until tender... the breasts were all roasted then frozen for future use. I've had enough turkey for a while. (turkey's for the homeless))